# How can I detect a buffer overflow using pointers in C?

Tags: c, pointers, buffer-overflow

I am studying the buffer overflows, and till now I have seen many examples using arrays, but I have a question about the following code:

```
void foo(){
    struct {
        char a[4];
        char b[16];
        char *p;
    } s;

    scanf("%s", s.p);
    printf("flag: %s", s.p);
}

int main(){
    foo();
}
```

Can the scanf with `s.p` as a parameter cause a buffer overflow? If yes, how I forecast where the string written in scanf is saved (and so how much I have to write in order to overwrite the saved instruction pointer, and make the exploit work?).

I have analyzed the code with gdb and I can see that the string inserted in scanf overwrite starting from the position of the array `a[]`, but I don't get if this always happens or if the string is saved in a "random" place.

Comment: Probably no because no buffer to overflow is assigned to `s.p`. Might be yes when the indeterminate value of `p` happens to become an address of some buffer.

Comment: `s.p` is an uninitialised pointer, though. What memory does it point to?

Comment: @ForceBru So since it is not initialized I don't know where the string will be saved, right?

Comment: @Luke correct...

Comment: @Luke: Technically, _anything_ can happen, including saving the string in the root sector of your harddisk. That's called Undefined Behavior, and it's bad.

Comment: @MSalters Ok perfect, so in theory I may use it for my bufferoverflow, but technically I am not sure about the position of the string...

Comment: It's not really a buffer, so it would be wrong to characterize the behavior as a "buffer overflow".  It's just undefined behavior.

Comment: In C (and C++) one should aim to *prevent* buffer overflows, rather than to *detect* them.

Comment: `s.p` points nowhere, so what is `scanf("%s", s.p);` supposed to do?

Answer (score 1):

A "buffer overflow" means you're writing past the end of an array that already belongs to you and clobbering whatever immediately follows it.

The problem you're asking about is different, because the initial value of `s.p` is *indeterminate* - it may not correspond to a writable address at all, in which case you will (most likely) trigger a segfault.  It's not a buffer overflow so much as it is just trying to access a random address in your process space.  The pointer value is *invalid* (meaning it doesn't point to an object in your program during that object's lifetime), but there's no (good, standard, portable) way to tell whether a non-`NULL` pointer value is valid or not.

Like writing past the end of an array, the behavior of attempting to read or write through an invalid pointer is *undefined*, meaning that neither the compiler nor the runtime environment are required to handle it in any particular way.  The behavior is not guaranteed to be predictable or repeatable; it can even vary from run to run of the same binary in the same environment (although in practice that tends to be consistent).  If you don't clobber anything "important" your code will execute with no *apparent* issues.

For this reason it's nearly impossible to detect or recover from a buffer overflow or writing through an invalid pointer after the fact.  Your time is much better spent *preventing* buffer overflows and writing through invalid pointers from happening in the first place.